# What's wrong with my screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

The screen anomaly doesn't look like other dead pixels I've seen before. Does anyone know what's causing this? It's a 15" MBP, early 2011, hi-res, matt display. You can only see it on light backgrounds.
[image]

Comment: Looks like dust between the top laminate and the LCD screen...

Comment: Is that a white spot in the screen?

Comment: @stuffe thanks for the response. Guess that's better than a dead pixel.

Comment: @MrDaniel yes it is. But it only show when on a light background. You can see it over dark colors.

Comment: So you can't see it when you have a dark background?

Comment: @MrDaniel nope, you can't.

Comment: Have you taken it into Apple and see what they say, it does not appear to be physical damage like being crushed, since it is dependent on screen color and not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a pressure mark where the panel has been hit by something

Comment: I took it to the apple store yesterday and that's what they said. They said it isn't very bad and they wouldn't expect it to get worse.

Comment: It shouldn't get any worse no. Just make sure you don't have anything on your keyboard when you close the lid :)